# CSS Animations with transform attribute not applying final state

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-animations

I am trying to animate an element's transform property, but I noticed it's not working as I expect on IE (surprisingly).

when animating from

```
0% { transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(150px); }
```

to

```
100% { transform: translateX(-50%); }
```

It seems to ignore the `translateX(-50%);`

This is the way I use the animation on the html element (I use forwards so the final state of the animation is the one that remains applied to the element):

```
animation: myanimation 1s ease-out forwards;
```

I've being trying to solve this for a while, even trying from `translate(-50%, 150px)` to `translate(-50%, 0px)` but still it won't work.

Here's a working [fiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LmYvYN) to quickly see the difference. It works well on Chrome, but misbehaves on IE.

Answer (score 1):

use `transform: translate(X, Y)` it works on IE ( use vendor prefix for IE9 `-ms-transform` )

```css
@keyframes myanimation {
    0% { transform: translate(50%, 150px); } /* i suppose -50% is a typo, if it's not replace it with -50% */
  100% { transform: translate(-50%, 0); }
}
#anim {
    display: inline-block;
    animation: myanimation 1s ease-out forwards;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="anim">Hello World</h1>
```

Comment: no it's not a typo, he want to have -50% on the X and only change the Y --> check his fiddle

Comment: but yeah with transform: `translate(-50%, 150px)` to `translate(-50%, 150px)` it works, it's just weird how IE just ignores it when using translateX

Answer (score 0):

You want to animate X from -50% to -50%? If you want to animate the Y coordinate, then set the value on your target percent.

```
100% { transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0); }
```

why not? This works on IE. I've tested.

Comment: thanks, but I do wanted to translate from -50% to -50%, I actually am after the root of the problem